# HP Image Assistant - User prompt restart

Tags: windows, powershell

As a company, we want to automate our driver updates using HP Image Assistant. We use the command line:

`C:\hpiasw\HPImageAssistant.exe /Operation:Analyze /Category:All /selection:All /Action:Install /Noninteractive /reportFolder:c:\hpiasw\report`

It's working well but the laptop restarts without any prompt. We would like to avoid the endpoint restarting automatically or prompting the user to defer or do it now.
I don't find any parameters in the HPIA documentation about this.

From the HPIA documentation there is no command to prompt the user. So I was wondering if from a powershell script we could kind of analyze every softpaq HPIA download to check which one needs a restart and deploy them with msiexec or something else that could prompt the user to restart while the download is done.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing `/Noninteractive` and/or adding `/Wait`?

Comment: When I removed the `/Noninteractive` it launched the GUI which we don't want either'code'